# Enotez: align number with heading

Tags: vertical-alignment, enotez

By default, enotez produces a listing with the numbers a bit "too much" to the left, i.e., to the left of the corresponding heading. See for example its own manual, on p. 10: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enotez/enotez_en.pdf.

My question is: how can I make the numbers align with the heading? I have a "hackish" way of kinda fixing it (shown below), but I would like to ask if there is a proper way of doing this. Thank you for your help!

(By the way, I got this misaligned result however I used enotez, so I think a MWE is not necessary -- but I can provide one if necessary.)

Here is the hack to align the numbers and the heading (the `1.25em` value was the result of trial and error):

```
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{format=\footnotesize\leftskip1.25em}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example so that people can test your code and suggest modifications.